# Laravel - production.ERROR: Undefined variable: department_chart_data in Chartjs barchart

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I am using chartjs bar chart in my Laravel-5.8

Controller

```
public function employee_goals()
{  
   //Goal-Department bar chart
    $department_record = DB::table('hr_employees')
             ->join('hr_departments', 'hr_departments.id', '=', 'hr_employees.department_id')
             ->select('hr_departments.dept_name AS department', DB::raw('COUNT(hr_employees.department_id) AS count'))
             ->where('hr_employees.company_id', $userCompany)
             ->where('hr_employees.hr_status',0)
             ->whereIn('hr_employees.employee_code', $publishedgoals)
             ->groupBy('hr_employees.department_id', 'hr_departments.dept_name')
             ->orderBy('hr_departments.dept_name', 'asc')
             ->get();    

    $department_data = [];
    foreach($department_record as $row) {
       $department_data['department_label'][] = $row->department;
       $department_data['department_data'][] = (int) $row->count;
    }
   $department_data['department_chart_data'] = json_encode($department_data); 

    return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals',$department_data);
```

I have used the same code for chartjs donut, and it works.

view

```
            <div class="chart">
              <canvas id="empDepartment" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></canvas>
            </div>

<script src="{{ asset('theme/adminlte3/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>

    var departmentData = JSON.parse(`<?php echo $department_chart_data; ?>`);
    var departmentChartCanvas = $('#empDepartment').get(0).getContext('2d')
    var departmentData        = {

    labels: departmentData.department_label,
        datasets: [
        {
        data: departmentData.department_data,
          backgroundColor : [
                '#f56954', 
                '#00a65a', 
                '#f39c12', 
                '#00c0ef',               
          ],
                borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1          
         }  
      ]
    }
    var departmentOptions     = {
      maintainAspectRatio : true,
      responsive : true,
    cutoutPercentage: 80,

    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
          var total = data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
          var pct = 100 / total * value;
          var pctRounded = Math.round(pct * 10) / 10;
          return value + ' (' + pctRounded + '%)';
        }
      }
    }

    }

     var departmentChart = new Chart(departmentChartCanvas, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: departmentData,
      options: departmentOptions      
     })
```

When I tried to load the page, I got this error

> production.ERROR: Undefined variable: department_chart_data

And its pointing to this line:

```
var departmentData = JSON.parse(`<?php echo $department_chart_data; ?>`);
```

I have tried several method yet the problem is unresolved.

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: instead of `return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals',$department_data);` try `return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals', compact('department_data'))` let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals',$department_data);
```

The second parameter to the `view()` helper method needs to be an array.

You should be able to resolve the issue by changing to this:

```
 return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals', [
   'department_data' => $department_data,
 ]);
```

As Daniel Logvin alluded to, the compact() method is commonly used here to remove duplication in setting the array keys, and this should accomplish the same thing:

```
 return view('report.employee_goal_statistics.employee_goals', compact($department_data));
```

The `view()` helper method is discussed a little bit more at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#creating-views

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too late to answer,but by using laravel 5.8 and this case ,I just think your problem in routing see web.php file careful .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).